# Transparent background affects text mesh in front

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a plane behind a text mesh 3d that i use to make the text more visible. The plane is supposed to be slitghtly transparent but when i give it a transparent shader it starts acting like the pane is in front of the text when it actually is not. How can i fix this?

[image]

Comment: Well from your screenshot it does indeed look like the plane is in front of the text, but I can't say for sure it is as I cant see the inspector values of both objects

Comment: Btw, you can also get TextMeshPro for free now from the asset store if you dont want to use the blurry text mesh that comes by default.

Comment: Both the transparent mesh you have selected, and the text, are in the Transparent render queue, but the text is being rendered first (likely due to a setting somewhere), but the rendering engine doesn't know that the transparent plane shouldn't render on top of what has already been drawn (i.e. transparent rendering queue assumes a back-to-front drawing order).

Comment: @Eddge Thanks! I now switched to TMP! Looks great. :)

Comment: @Draco18s oh no! Any idea on how to fix it ? :o

Comment: The thing is, when i view it from a certain angle it looks like it should,but when i rotate the camera a little bit some of the forefront texts suddenly looks like they are behind. But they are in front!

Comment: The camera angle thing is because the two objects are not being depth sorted properly. There may not be an easy fix to that. TextMeshPro might work, or you could use the Canvas UI text (with the canvas set to World Space).

Comment: Thanks @Draco18s . Ive tried with TMP, UI text in world space and in overlay. Ive tried with a 3d pane as background and with a UI sprite as background. Still the same problem.

Comment: Okej i solved it using a canvas, TextMeshPro- text and as background i use a UI Image. That works as i intended.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and found the solution:
Go on the canvas, and increase "Order in layer" until it is fixed (if it doesn't work after like 4 or 5, sry it might be something else ^^')

If it works it simply meant that the UI text was rendered before the transparent material, so you wanna tell the canvas to render itself after the material.

Answer (score 0):

Okej i solved it using a canvas, TextMeshPro- text and as background i use a UI Image. That works as i intended.